# Sequel -C copy database runs succesfully but does not copy any of the records in any table

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

I am trying to copy my sqlite3 database to a postgresql database. It runs succesfully, but no data is inserted into the tables. What is the cause? I am using the Sequel database toolkit Ruby Gem. I cannot use pg_loader, I am on windows.

```
sequel -C sqlite:db.sqlite3 postgres://username:password@localhost/database
```

```
Databases connections successful
Migrations dumped successfully
Tables created
Begin copying data
Finished copying data
Begin creating indexes
Finished creating indexes
Begin adding foreign key constraints
Finished adding foreign key constraints
Primary key sequences reset successfully
Database copy finished in 1.0044088 seconds
```

Comment: what did you do to determine it did "not copy any of the records" ?

Comment: I viewed the tables in PG admin and 0 records were in the database when I selected view data

Comment: Per [the documentation](https://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/bin_sequel_rdoc.html#label-Copy+Databases), `sequel -c` "... is best designed for quick conversions and testing. For serious production use, use the database's tools to copy databases for the same database type, and for different database types, use the Sequel API." Did you try using the `--echo` or `--log logfile` flags to have Sequel echo its commands so you can verify the data was copied?